# Size of Drawings in Picture Box when maximized then normalized

Tags: vb.net, drawing, picturebox

I have a form that contains a picture box.  In the code-behind, I draw some things in this picture box.  The size of these drawings depend on the size of the picture box (for example, a circle whose width is 90% of the box's width).  When the form loads, it is in normal state, and it looks fine.  I can maximize the form, and when I do the controls size accordingly and the drawings in the picture box also size accordingly - so that all looks good.  The issue is when I then restore the form back to a normal state:  the controls resize accordingly, but the drawings in the picture box do not (therefore some of it is cut off because it's too large).  I tried using the Me.Resize event to call the logic that makes the drawings, but for some reason when that is called it still thinks the width of the picture box is the width when in the maximized state.

So why do the graphics in the picture box resize fine when you maximize the form, but not when you restore it to normal?

And why would it still think the box's width is that while maximized, not actually the width when normal which is the state it's now in?

Is there a way to get around this so I can make sure the graphics will resize correctly?

Note:  I would try using the ResizeEnd event instead, but that is not raised when you maximize or restore the form.  I don't know why that is, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 2 questions are hard to answer without seeing the code.  If you are drawing on a control, then you should force the recalc and repaint from an event for that control.  It might be how or what you are doing in the events.

`Is there a way to get around this so I can make sure the graphics will resize correctly?`

I used a panel and the `ClientSizeChanged` event and it works fine whether the form is manually sized or Min and Maxed:

```
Private myRect As Rectangle
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RecalcRect()
End Sub

Private Sub pnl_ClientSizeChanged(sender As Object, 
       e As EventArgs) Handles pnl.ClientSizeChanged
    RecalcRect()
    pnl.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub RecalcRect()
    myRect = New Rectangle(0, 0, pnl.Width, pnl.Height)
    myRect.Inflate(-10, -10)
End Sub

Private Sub pnl_Paint(sender As Object, 
          e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pnl.Paint
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.OrangeRed, myRect)
End Sub
```

`Recalc` could be called from or even done in the Paint event, I was trying to emulate something similar to what you described with the calcs elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, the logic that makes the drawings is called in the form's Paint event.  So I added to make that same call in the picture box's ClientSizeChanged event, like you have, and that worked!  Thank you!